# Mono jack output to stereo headphones : how to send the mono signal to both sides?

Tags: audio, soldering, stereo

I have a 3.5mm jack mono output. I'm plugging standard stereo headphones into this jack, and it plays only on one side. I want the sound to come out on both sides in the headphones (same signal, but in both ears).

How can I cut and wire so that the mono signal goes into both speakers ?

I know there are some adapters on Internet that should do the job, but it's not an option anymore since I have to only 1½ day to finish this…

Comment: solder the mono signal wire to both of the stereo (left and right) wires and bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw86s7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks rather simple. Does it mean I can just cut the cable of the headphones and fuse together the wires corresponding to the tip and the ring ?

Comment: Yes, and you would leave the old wire that goes to Ring unconnected (assuming there is a wire there at all)

Comment: Yes suggested mod sure will work but there is something you need to know about plugging in the mono plug into the stereo jack. The longer sleeve of the mono plug will short circuit the ring contact point of one of the audio channel to the ground. Some equipment such as portable audio players won't be happy with this. You may end up blowing their headphone power amplifier.

Comment: @soosaisteven Thank you for the warning. The case is a little bit different here though: I want to plug a stereo plug into a mono jack (not a mono plug into a stereo jack). Is there still a problem in this case?

Comment: In response to @soosaisteven's concern, use of a stereo plug at both ends solves that problem. The lead should be labelled "mono" and "stereo" at each connector. Schematic modified to suit.

Comment: @transistor So if I understand well, if I cut only within the stereo cable and join the tip and ring wires as indicated in your schematic, and I keep the stereo plug at the end (with the ring unconnected), I should be ok, right? I'll be trying later today.

Comment: That's correct. The fact that you got it to play on one speaker indicates that the tip and sleeve are used on the mono output.