# Mono output to stereo input

Tags: bluetooth, wiring, sound, stereo

Recently I've been into the idea of hooking up a Bluetooth receiver to my car stereo via my car radio's aux input. I got a Bluetooth receiver module from an old Bluetooth speaker that I had laying around. I disconnected to speaker and, not surprisingly, it was a mono speaker output on the circuit board. I took an aux cable, cut it open, wrapped the left and right together and soldered it to the positive output and soldered the ground wire to the negative output on the board. I plugged it into my car, connected to the module with my iPhone and played Spotify... It worked, but audio only came through the left side of the stereo car system.

My question is: Is there anyway to play the mono sound through both stereo speakers?

Comment: Duplicate? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/241614/104462

Comment: Sounds like you tried to do the right thing. Are you sure you connected the wires correctly?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I'm not sure the answers to that question helps me directly

Comment: I'm 90% sure that I connected it good... The aux cable had 3 wires inside(red, white and blue). I assumed that the red and white were left and right connections because my old tv had audio jacks that were those colors. I twisted the red and white wires together and connected it to the positive mono sound output in the board, and the blue one to the negative... Sound only comes through the left speaker in my car.

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything about the colours. Try red and blue together to + and white to - instead. Or use a meter to check which colour is which.

Comment: Assuming the aux input is stereo, and the wire didn't have insulation on it, it should work. Unless the colors don't match. Use a multimeter to test. Not that you should connect an amplified speaker output to a line level input. Are you sure a normal audio input has stereo? And you know dedicated Bluetooth aux input devices are only a few bucks on ebay.

Comment: What you mentioned about I shouldn't connect an amplified speaker output to a line level input worries me that this could short out my speakers or something. Could that happen? And what would happen if I connected the wrong wire to + and -? Also,I know I could get a dedicated after market one for a couple bucks, but I would just love to accomplish this diy way, just buying it is absolute last resort

Comment: It is common to add coupling capacitors between amplifier stages to remove any DC component.  Also (FYI), there are many bluetooth protocols.  Bluetooth A2DP is high fidelity stereo with some latency.  Bluetooth HSF is lower fidelity mono with less latency and a reverse direction channel for talking.

Comment: I had the wiring wrong, through trial and error, I figured out the red and blue were left and right and white was ground. I also got another Bluetooth module from one of those Bluetooth earpieces that use to be popular. I don't think it has an amplifier built in(I don't think it would need to) so that solves that worry. Thanks everyone for your responses.